# What is an XML node with a one-sided tag called, and how can I create one of these in the XmlDocument class?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, nodes

The node I'm referring to is formed like this:

```
<MyElement Text="Testing!" Color="Red" />
```

I say "one-sided tag" because I can't think of any other way to describe it.

How would I programmatically create one of these in an `XmlDocument` in C#?

Comment: Normally a _one-sided tag_ is created when it doesn't contain contents. This depends on the serializer, because it is the same as `<MyElement Text="Testing!" Color="Red"></MyElement>`

Comment: A xml could be created by the XmlSerializer, XmlDocument, XDocument and could be written _(serialized)_ like `<name />` or `<name></name>`, look to my example below with the `XDocument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();

XElement root = new XElement(XName.Get("MyElement"));

root.Add(new XAttribute(XName.Get("Text"), "Testing!"));
root.Add(new XAttribute(XName.Get("Color"), "Red"));

xdoc.Add(root);


Trace.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```

results in:

```
<MyElement Text="Testing!" Color="Red" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct name for these tags is "empty-element tags".